# Why is react-font-picker gives error "Error: Cannot update active font: "Fira Sans" is not in the font list"?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using font picker in my project like this.

```
<FontPicker
                          apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}
                          activeFontFamily={activeFontFamilyMobile}
                          onChange={(nextFont) =>
                            setActiveFontFamilyMobile(nextFont.family)
                          }
                        />
```

The already saved font in stored in the backend, which I am fetching and setting up like this in use Effect:

```
            setActiveFontFamilyMobile(response.data.font_family);
```

and by default, the state is like this:

```
  const [activeFontFamilyMobile, setActiveFontFamilyMobile] = React.useState("Raleway");
```

So the problem is that when the page loads for the first time, saved font_family comes from the backend and is stored in activeFontFamilyMobile. And in the parameters of fontPicker, it should be displayed by activeFontFamily={activeFontFamilyMobile}. But it gives error like this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKEWm.png)

But if I make some changes in the code and cause a re-render, it starts working. So its not working when the pages loads first time. What might be the issue?